# How many times of comparison during the insertion sort and selection sort in the worst case?

Tags: python, sorting

To practice coding, I wrote the insertion sort and selection sort in Python.
Here is the insertion sort:

```
def insertion(L, i):
    a = L[i + 1]
    for index in range(i + 1):
        if L[index] > a:
            break
    else:
        index = i + 1
    for k in range(i + 1, index, -1):
        L[k] = L[k - 1]
    L[index] = a
    return L
def insertion_sort(L):
    for i in range(len(L) - 1):
        L = insertion(L, i)
    return L
```

Here is the selection sort:

```
def selection_sort(L):
    for i in range(len(L) - 1):
        _min = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(L)):
            if L[j] < L[_min]:
                _min = j
        L[_min], L[i] = L[i], L[_min]
    return L
```

Then I use **N = 10000;L = [i for i in range(N, 0, -1)]** to create the worst case. In my perspective, the insertion sort is quicker than the selection sort because the comparison times of selection is 49,995,000 while the insertion is only 9999 times. But when I use

```
import time
start = time.time()
……
end = time.time()
```

to measure the time, the result is that the insertion sort is slower than the selection sort.
Do I misunderstand the times of comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed you have missed something. Even if you are not comparing more in insertion sort, you go over the list and change all the values in the second for loop, because index = 0 in the case of
L=[j for j in range(N, 0, -1)] for every i. So the time complexity is also O(n^2). The same as in selection sort.

However, I can't understand why it takes more time than selection sort. It might be because you are calling to insertion (the function inside insertion_sort) and python is using additional memory and time.

Comment: The reason why the selection sort is faster than the insertion sort may be that the times of moving data, which is related to the specific input, in selection sort is less than that in insertion sort.